# Need to Install different versions of teamviewer on same linux ubunto distro

Tags: teamviewer

I need to have 2 different versions of teamviewer (version 8 and version 12) at the same time on a Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS system.
How do i install them both? 
What console commands do i have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is via LXD.

I'd first start with Ubuntu Zesty (17.04) + then create two LXD containers.

One container running TeamViewer V8 + another running V12.

Trying to install both versions side by side is doable + you'll have a massive amount of work ahead of you.

Running LXD is the quickest way to a working install, which anyone can understand how to maintain.